# The future in the deflationary theory of truth

Tags: truth, paradox

How does the deflationary theory of truth, which defines *true* and *false* in the following straightforward way

> The proposition that *p* is true iff *p*.
>
> The proposition that *p* is false iff *p* is not true.

deal with problems à la Aristotle’s sea battle?

I now accept that there are solutions for other theories of truth, but for the deflationary theory, I don’t see how it can get out of this paradox:

> *p* ∨ ¬*p* ⇒ (using the definition) ⇒ ((*p* is true) ∨ (¬*p* is true))

So with *p* = “There will be a sea battle tomorrow”, we get:

“It is true, that there will be a sea battle tomorrow. Or it is false, that there will be a sea battle tomorrow”.

Which is incompatible with an undetermined future.

A very different interpretation can result if we do not use the deflationary definition. Here we stop at *p* ∨ ¬*p* being a tautology and inserting *p* = “There will be a sea battle tomorrow” which yields the unobjectionable “There will be a sea battle tomorrow or there will not be a sea battle tomorrow”.

Comment: Deflationary theory of truth does not define truth at all. It simply says that there is nothing to the truth beyond Tarski's Convention T: "p" is true iff p. Deflationists need not be wedded to bivalence or classical logic, especially when time-dependent statements are explicitly involved. Another popular approach is to distinguish truth and necessity, and write off the paradox as a [modal fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_future_contingents#The_modal_fallacy).

Comment: @Conifold well, they don’t need to define the concept, since they regard truth as shallow. But they still have to define the words “true” and “false”. If they hold on to classical logic and use the definition in the first yellow box in my question, the principle of bivalence directly follows.

Comment: @Conifold with the principle of bivalence, this results in *“It is true, that there will be a sea battle tomorrow. Or it is false, that there will be a sea battle tomorrow”*. If we stick to the extremely common notion of “true” as being constant over time, determinism follows. If we reject this notion, the deflationary theory seems to define the word “true” in a way few people understand it.

Comment: "True" is only constant over time for "eternal" statements of mathematics et al. It is very common (and was likely Aristotle's position) to say that the truth value of p about tomorrow is simply undefined today, as there is nothing yet for it to be true about. Those who want truth values defined for technical reasons have the option of moving this over to modal logic, where truth does not imply necessity. Hence p being true today does not entail fatalism because it need not be true *necessarily*.

Comment: @Conifold going from undefined to true is normal. But not from true to false or from false to true. The point is that I don’t see how deflationary theory can make room for “undefined”.

Comment: Convention T only applies to well-formed sentences. Some of today's sentences about tomorrow's events are not well-formed, and their truth values are undefined. Alternatively, they are all well-formed and true/false in every possible timeline, but some of them are contingent. Since it is open which timeline is actual their truth value does not determine the future.

Comment: @Conifold if there was a *decisive* refutation of deflationary theory, it’s unlikely that it would appear first in the comment section of philosophy.SE question, right?

Comment: It just shows that a lot of complexity lurks behind the the supposed simplicity of the deflationary theory. Like having to claim that a perfectly understandable sentence like *“there will be a sea battle tomorrow”* is not well-formed or proposing a complex theory of timelines and truth.

Comment: I think you are taking deflationary theory the way opposite to what is intended. It is not more complex than the rest, but less. *Any* theory that endorses Convention T (i.e. almost all of them) can be appropriated by a deflationist, they just write off the more substantive parts as additional conventions/technical devices. Pick your favorite solution from other theories, mine is [supervaluationism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/fut-cont/#SH2b). There is no refuting deflationism without refuting almost all other theories of truth.

Comment: As for "well-formed", it is "well-formed for having a truth value", not for being understandable, even the Liar and round squares are understandable. It is not really surprising, and intuitive, that future contingents are not so well-formed, or that colloquial semantics of them involves branching timelines. Except deflationists do not really care what the intended semantics is, to them we just introduce modality or truth value gaps, and extra devices for handling them, supervaluationism or something else. Whatever is handy to clean up the colloquial usage coherently. It is a nominalistic view.

Comment: @Conifold well, I see something quite circular in *The proposition that p is true iff p and p is well-formed for having a truth value*; this circularity was missing in the original *The proposition that p is true iff p.*

Comment: It would only be circular if to determine what is "well-formed to have a truth value" one needed to apply Convention T. As is, it is just my suggestive label that can be replaced by  ''grue". Of course, one has to give independent rules to determine what is grue, but it is not hard to do with future contingents. Convention T tells us how to use "true" given  sentences we wish to assert, it has nothing to say on what we should assert, or deem assertible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101444/discussion-between-wolf-revo-cats-and-conifold).